# Counting occurances in a list using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary

I currently have a list that looks like the following:

```
list = [me foo, i foobar, the barfoo, foo tool, the too]
```

I want to count the number of exact instances of "foo" OR "too", but it would exclude "barfoo" and "tool".

I can do a simple search using the following code (which returns the right results), but I'd like to use regular expressions on "foo" and "too". Any help?

```
sum(('foo' in i or 'too' in i) for i in list)
```

I'm familiar with the following code, though I can't get it to work with a list.

```
import re
re.search(r'\bfoo\b', list)
```

Comment: Why do you add the word boundry `\b` ? Is that an extra requirement?

Comment: @sln no it's not. just my attempt at shitty regex. any regex elements are fine.

Comment: Its better to state what you expect to be matched, nobody's an expert in regex. `\b` eliminates a whole bunch more than `exclude "barfoo" and "tool".`

Comment: A simple regex if python does lookarounds `(?<!bar)foo|too(?!l)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's similar - you just need to convert the result of the `re.search` into a bool.  `re.search` will be `None` if no match is found - ie `False` - otherwise `True`.

```
li = ['me foo', 'i foobar', 'the barfoo', 'foo tool', 'the too']

sum(bool(re.search(r'\b(f|t)oo\b',x)) for x in li)
Out[80]: 3
```

(standard reminder not to name your lists `list` goes here)